# How to let angular $asyncValidator fire on blur but normal validators on input

Tags: angularjs, validation

Is it possible to let angular 1.3 $asyncValidators only fire on blur and not as the user inputs? I want the $validators to behave as per default.

I know I can use `ng-model-options` to update the model onBlur but then all validations are fired on blur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (angularjs version 1.3) there is no mechanism to do this.

In the end I added a blur event to fire the validators and then set the validity

```
element.on('blur', function () {
    if (ngModel.$dirty) {
        doServerSideValidation();
    } else {
        ngModel.$setValidity(key, true);
    }
});
```

The `doServerSideValidation()` function will set the validity of the `ngModel` after doing the request.