# Asynchronous validation on blur Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular JS 1.5.6 and I would like to perform asynchronous input validation that would occure only on blur. I specify that this directive is used with other directives so I can neither use modelOption: {debounce: 500} nor use modelOption: {updateOn: 'blur'}.

I have tryied the code bellow but curiously on the first blur, no async validation is done, and when I come back to the input the async validation is performed for each typed character, which is exactly what I would like to avoid.

```
function blurFocusDirective($http, $q) {
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elm, attrs, modelCtrl) {
    elm.on('blur', function() {
      console.log('capture blur event');

      modelCtrl.$asyncValidators.myValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return $http.get('/username-check/' + modelValue).then(
          function(response) {
            if (!response.data.validUsername) {
              return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
            }
            return true;
          }
        );
      };
    });
  }
};
```

}

I have [plunkered](https://plnkr.co/edit/L5mIAk?p=preview) the issue, press F12 to see what is happening in the console.

I precise that the WS '/username-check/' is a fake, it is not linked to the issue I want to solve. My issue is that the async HTTP request is done at each typed character, whereas I would like it to be done only on blur

Comment: `/username-check` doesn't exist in the plunkr, so no validation is being done there.

Comment: @Blazemonger: This WS is a fake, it is not linked to the issue I want to solve. My issue that the async HTTP request is done at each typed character, whereas I would like it to be done only on blur

Comment: Why can't you use ng-model-options directive to specify the updateOn? I tried it and it's working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/kC2v5JNBYPfzPkGuhMU4

Comment: @Dola: As specified I can not use ng-model-options because I am using this directive with other directive on my real project. Using debounce or updateOn would cause the other directive to behave not like they are supposed to.

Comment: What about setting the validation manually? ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081293/how-to-let-angular-asyncvalidator-fire-on-blur-but-normal-validators-on-input

Comment: It sounds like your first blur may be attaching rather than performing your action. Side note: Try `jQuery._data(elm, 'events')` to check what events are on the element and make sure they are what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a issue with your code. Every time, when `onblur` event occurs, when creating new async validator! It validator working every time, when `ngModel` is changed.

Try this. You can set validation manually.

```
elm.on('blur', function() {
      console.log('capture blur event');

      $http.get('/username-check/' + modelCtrl.$modelValue).then(
        function(response) {
          if (response.data.validUsername)
            modelCtrl.$setValidity("myValidation",true);
          else
            modelCtrl.$setValidity("myValidation",false);
        }
      ).catch(function() {
        modelCtrl.$setValidity("myValidation",false);
      });

    });
```

Example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/feGW4gJj8Y57JkmBti2f?p=preview)

Comment: you rock. Thanx a lot